# SHA256: Padding a 512 bits length message

Tags: c++, cryptography, hashcode, sha

I am currently implementing the SHA256 hash-algorithm for a "custom-built" embeded-device.
Obviously I have a problem with message padding. 
The routine I wrote does not work with message whose size **equals exactly 512 bits**.

In that case, how should the message be padded ?
i.e.

```
M = "AABBCCDDEEFFGGHHIIJJKKLLMMNNOOPP"
```

Z.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Even though it starts out as exactly 512 bits, you still need to pad the message.

[FIPS 180-4](http://csrc.nist.gov/publications/fips/fips180-4/fips-180-4.pdf), §5.1.1 explains it as follows:

> Suppose that the length of the message, M, is L bits. Append the bit “1” to the end of the message, followed by k zero bits, where k is the smallest, non-negative solution to the equation L + 1+ k ≡ 448 mod 512 . Then append the 64-bit block that is equal to the number L expressed using a binary representation.

[I substituted `L` for a character that wasn't displaying correctly]

Comment: I tried so. But I didn't get the expected result.
Would you please give a detailed hexa-representation of the padding block ?

Comment: How about an implementation that passes all the tests I've thrown at it? http://codereview.stackexchange.com/q/13288/489

Answer (score 0):

For data that is an exact multiple of the block size PKCS#7 padding says you must add a block of padding with each byte set to the number of padding bytes. In the case of AES the block size is 16 bytes so add 16-bytes each with the value 0x10.

See [PKCS#7 padding](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Padding_(cryptography)#PKCS7)

Note: PHP mcrypt does not do PKCS#7 padding, it must be done by user code.